# Alias for git command

Tags: linux, terminal, git

is there a way to make an alias for creating, a new branch?
For example, I want to type "feat" and get something like "feature/blabla-" so I will need to add just a number.

i want to type git checkout 'feat' press tab for example and get 'git checkout feature/blabla'

Comment: where you type `feat`? after `git ...` or as its own command? and could you spell out what you want the new command to look like?

Comment: You're most likely going to want a function

Comment: i want to type git checkout feat press tab for example and get git checkout feature/blabla-

Comment: @4knort Welcome to the site. If you want an answer then I recommend that you say that in your question? (you can edit your own question).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well, what you can do is tinker with your *.gitconfig* (probably on your home) like this (if you have git configured):

```
[alias]
  feat = checkout
```

and you will can do this: `git feat`.

Other ways to do:

```
$ git config --global alias.st status
```

On unix, use single quotes if the alias has a space:

```
$ git config --global alias.ci 'commit -v'
```

On windows, use double quotes if the alias has a space or a command line argument:

```
c:\dev> git config --global alias.ci "commit -v"
```

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553786/how-do-i-alias-commands-in-git)

In case your doubt is not this, I'm sorry.

Comment: i want to type "git checkout feat" and get "git checkout feature/blabla-" I want to create a branch faster

Comment: Using this alias you can type: git feat name_of_branch

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with bash-completion for git. Asciinema recording below.

Installation or configuration depends on your OS.

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 0):

You could define a shell variable `feat=feature/blabla`, and then use `git checkout $feat-7`. In some shells (zsh for example, but not in bash), you can then press <kbd>tab</kbd> after `$feat` to expand it directly to `feature/blabla`.

[Demonstration](https://asciinema.org/a/hLKXGIjVJQhcIE4M5RmW2Yzp3)

The downside is the added dollar sign, but the upside is that it works in pretty much every shell by simply adding that variable definition.